# When I run mocha tests in my project, it can't be terminated after test

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mocha.js, chai

I am using mocha for test.

Here is my testcase.

```
const mysql_service = require('../../router/mysql_service')

const chai = require('chai')
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;
describe('mysql_service', function () {
  this.timeout(20000)
  it('#qryInterconnectionStocks', function (done) {
      mysql_service.qryInterconnectionStocks(20)
      .then(function(result)  {
        expect(result).not.to.be.null
        expect(Array.isArray(result)).to.be.true
        // console.log(result)
        done()
      },function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        expect(err).to.be.null
        done(err)
      })

  })
})
```

First, I run test command

```
mocha test/**/*.js
```

It success, but the terminal don't exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `--exit` flag to `mocha` command to make it exit, see [breaking changes](https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit).

Comment: @Owen.Zhao You are welcome to accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: @Owen.Zhao you might wanna upvote the answer too. Be generous!

Comment: @Willa Thanks, I see. Two years ago, I was totally a rookie with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see. The reason the process cannot exit is my mysql connection is not closed, so the process cannot exit util all of the processes are closed.